# How to start an activity in the onPause method?

Tags: android

I have a webview and when I do some java-script processing on it. I click on a link to play a video, after the video finishes in full screen. I want to return to my webpage in the same state I left it before clicking to play the video.

How can I do it?

Any snippets?

Thanks,
Sana.

Answer (score 0):

After playing the video, I over wrote the method onCompletion with finish() activity to kill the video and return to the previous activity!

I know this is not clean but anyone has some other way to do it please let me know!